# Electrum - Why do I have to Restore every time I use it?

Tags: electrum

I did not forget my password. I have been done dozens of transactions with Electrum, and every time I try to send bitcoins, I get "Invalid Password". So I restore from seed, set a new password, use it to make a transaction, or two, but it seems after a few hours it somehow expires. This method works, but is mysterious and annoying.

Comment: Have you tried re installing Electrum? And are you using the latest version of the software? (Perhaps avoid using beta versions, if available.)

Comment: It's Electrum 1.9.8. No, I haven't tried to reinstall - that would likely fix it, now that you mention it. But it's working for me as it is, and I'm loath to mess with something that I entrust with moolah.